# Spring IO POST form is redirecting to the wrong URL - Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, forms, spring-mvc

I have a form for uploading a file on a site I'm coding. From the URL http://localhost:8080/uploadRevision/{docId} It should be directing to the URL http://localhost:8080/uploadRevisionLanding and then redirected back to the userDashboard.

However when I submit the form it takes me to http://localhost:8080/uploadRevision/uploadRevisionLanding so it's appending /uploadRevisionLanding to the URL rather than going from the root (sorry if this isn't the right terminology).

I'm using SpringIO and Thymeleaf and I'd coded something else to work a similar way which works fine.

My form

```
<form name="upload" action="/" th:action="@{uploadRevisionLanding}" th:object="${document}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="container">
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <strong>Upload files</strong> <small>
                </small>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <label class="control-label" >Title:</label>
                    <label class = "docTitle" th:text="${document.title}" />
                    <label class="control-label">Select File:</label>

                    <input id="input-2" type="file" name="file" class="file"/>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default file-preview-clear" value="Reset">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                        Clear </button>
                    <!-- file-preview-input -->
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-labeled btn-primary" value="Submit">
                            <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                        </span> Upload </button>
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                           value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Contoller methods

```
@GetMapping("/uploadRevision/{docId}")
public String uploadRevision(Model model, @PathVariable("docId") long docId) {
    /* Do something */
    return "/uploadRevision";
}

@PostMapping("/uploadRevisionLanding")
public RedirectView handleRevisionUpload (@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                          RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                                          @ModelAttribute Document document) {
    /* Load logged user */

     /* Set branch for file */

    return new RedirectView("/uploadRevisionLanding");
}

@GetMapping("/uploadRevisionLanding")
public ModelAndView uploadRevisionLanding() { return new ModelAndView("userDashboard"); }
```

In the controller methods I've tried returning the URL string both with and without the preceding "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I needed to have `th:action="@{uploadRevisionLanding}"` as `th:action="@{/uploadRevisionLanding}"` with a preceding "/" so that it was context-relative to the server root. It worked without it on another page that was slightly different which was what confused me.